# How to close a window in ZK?

Tags: java, zk

How to close a window in ZK without using window id on click of cancel button?

some code of zul file

```
<window apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer" width="700px"
        height="500px" title="ReDefault Folder" mode="modal" border="normal"
        closable="true"
        viewModel="@id('vm') @init('web.viewmodel.FolderRedefaultViewModel')" visible="@load(vm.showDialog)">

<x:table border="0" align="right">
                <x:tr>

                    <x:td align="right" width="20px">

                        <button label="OK" width="80px"
                            onClick="@command('insertDefaultOnOk')">
                        </button>
                    </x:td>
                    <x:td align="left">

                        <button label="Cancle" width="80px"
                            onClick="@command('nOk')">
                        </button>
                    </x:td>
                </x:tr>
            </x:table>
    </window>
```

on click of this button i want to close the window

Comment: Well, after ignoring all the ways the element is supposed to be closed, have you tried magic?

Comment: Will the "Event closeEvent = new Event("onClose", this.self, null) ;
Events.postEvent(closeEvent)" do?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: would you please elaborate, I want to close the window on click of ok and close button both

Comment: Please provider your ZUL-File / Java source.

Comment: @Jermaine Xu : not working for this.self. i mean this.self is not in my view model

Answer (score 6):

**You could try this:**
1. give your window an id: `<window id="mywin"...`
2. add onClick to your button: `<button onClick="mywin.detach()"...`

Or if you want to do it from **your command handler**, pass the window as a parameter:
1. `<window id="mywin"...`
2. `<button onClick="@command('test', cmp=mywin)"`
3.

```
@Command
public void test(@BindingParam("cmp")  Window x) {
    x.detach();
}
```

Or **without assigned id**:
Just use `getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent()` in the ZUL instead of `mywin`. This will get:

- button's parent: `td`
- td's parent: `tr`
- tr's parent `table`
- table's parent: `window`

Comment: Check the original post. I want to close window without using window id

Answer (score 0):

Basically it can be done by writing inside

```
<window apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer" width="700px"
        height="500px" title="ReDefault Folder" mode="modal" border="normal"
        closable="true"
        viewModel="@id('vm') @init('web.viewmodel.FolderRedefaultViewModel')" visible="@load(vm.showDialog)">
```

this:

```
<window apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer" width="700px"
        height="500px" title="ReDefault Folder" mode="modal" border="normal"
        closable="true"
        viewModel="@id('vm') @init('web.viewmodel.FolderRedefaultViewModel')" visible="@load(vm.showDialog)" onCancel="self.detach();">
```

In plain words just add `onCancel="self.detach();"` inside window